# How To Display Websocket Response To Browser In NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, websocket

I am new to NodeJS. My code is

```
 const webSocket= require('ws');
const express = 
 require('express');
 const app=express();
   Var url = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/BTCUSDT@trade`"
const ws = new webSocket(url);
  app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
 ws.on('message',data=>{
 res.send(data)
})
  })
app.listen(3000)
```

When i use console.log instead of res.send() it works successfully and consoled the data.

How can i display these dynamic data to a browser. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You need a client, show us your client code.

Comment: Doest have any client code.. am new to node

Comment: You mean to send a request to this above file?

Comment: I think it is better to understand how WebSockets works. In your code main problem is you get message listener if there is a call for "/" endpoint. Your api and websocket shouldn't depend each other. For websockets this is a server, to get messages to browser you need a websocket client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websocket is event-driven

The syntax for a event emmiter on the server which emit the event will be like the following:

```
ws.emit('eventName',data);
```

The syntax of a event listener which receives a message will be like the following:

```
//For the client to receive the message, you should put something like this at the front end

ws.on('eventName',data=>{ 

const content = data;
 document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML += content

 });
```

Websocket is a different protocol than HTTP. It uses HTTP established the connection. The connection will then be upgraded to websocket. By the time, you shouldn't HTTP to send data anymore like res.send() but instead use ws.emit('eventName', data) for example.

[Websocket Protocol](https://blog.wildix.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/BOSH-and-WebSocket-Transport-protocols.png)

Comment: ThankYou For Your Reply.. But How can i load 'ws' on that page for client side?

Comment: Yes. You just have to include the WebSocket CDN on the front end. You can also choose to download it locally as well.